# How to prevent depsgraph update triggers

Tags: python, properties, depsgraph

Any python or custom properties will send update signals to blender depsgraph, even when it is not necessary. This can be problematic when the properties are attached to an object with an intensive modifier, as the modifier will recalculate constantly when users are changing the property value.

**Is there a way for us, python developers, to prevent blender sending these update triggers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add-on developers are not able to stop updates to the dependency graph. The Python API only provides the ability to trigger updates, not to stop them.

Internally, developers call functions such as `DEG_id_tag_update` or `DEG_relations_tag_update` in C or C++ code to indicate that a dependecy graph update is required.

Comment: thanks! I was afraid of this answer

Do you have any advices when dealing with properties attached to obj with heavy-to-compute modifiers perhaps?

Comment: You could create your own custom UI that only syncs/updates values of the underlying modifier under specific circumstances (e.g. pressing an "update" button). However, you will not be able to stop users from manually changing the settings of the modifier directly, which would still cause issues.